# I want to convert a 3D numpy array from the format [g, list([f])] to [[g, f]]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm currently doing some work to extract NoData values from a gridded satellite image. The image is presented as a 2D array, where the inner array is every pixel value in a given row from left to right, and the outer array is every row in the image from top to bottom.

Any advice on this?

I have built the following functions:

```
from more_itertools import locate

def find_indices(liste, item):
    indices = locate(liste, lambda x: x == item)
    return list(indices)

def find_indices2(liste, item):
    indices = locate(liste, lambda x: item in x)
    return list(indices)
```

and I have built two separate arrays of the index positions of:
a) the rows containing a '0' value in them (all of them). This is a 1D array marked as 'f'
b) the pixels with a '0' value within their given row. This is a 2D array, marked as 'g'

Finally, I carried out the following to merge my two arrays.

```
h = np.dstack((g, f))
```

Which gives me a 3D array of the form [g, list([f])]. I.e. [[0, list([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...])], [1, list([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...])]].

I want to convert this array into the form [[g, f]]. I.e. [[0, 0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4]...]. This will essentially give me a set of 2D co-ordinates for each NoData pixel which I can then apply to a second satellite pixel to mask it, turn both satellite images to arrays of the same length and run a regression on them.

Comment: ```locate``` is not defined

Comment: apologies, fixed now.

Comment: can you give an example input and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood correctly what you mean, you could do something like this to convert your data:

```
data = np.array([[0, list([0, 1, 2, 3])], [1, list([0, 1, 2])]])

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    converted = np.asarray(np.meshgrid(data[i][0],data[i][1])).T.reshape(-1,2)
    print(converted)
    # and you could vstack here for example
```

This would give the output:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 3]]
[[1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]]
```

This can surely be done faster and more efficiently, but you didn't provide exact information on the data you start with. So I'm just trying to address the conversion part of the question. I think it's a bad idea to store data as list inside a numpy array in the first place, especially if its length varies.